# How can I delete a row from following table?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

Here is my code I am using pouchdb to display records in a table and then I want to delete a specific record by clicking the fontawesome trash icon. I have currently set the `"doc.rows[0].doc"` but it only deletes the first record no matter where you click.

```js
// Show Record
function showRecord() {
  db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    descending: false
  }, function(err,
    doc) {
    for (let i = 0; i < doc.rows.length; i++) {
      let obj = doc.rows[i].doc;
      let record = "<tr class='cursor'><td>" + obj._id + "</td><td>" +
        obj.Name + "</td><td>" + obj.FName + "</td><td>" + obj.Program + "</td>  <
        td > "  +
        obj.Start + "</td><td>" + obj.End + "</td><td>" + obj.Admission +
        "  <
        /td>  <
        td > " + obj.Price +" < /td><td><i class='fas fa-trash cursor' / > < /td>  <
        /tr>";
      tbody.innerHTML += record;
    }
  });
}
tbody.addEventListener("click", Del);

function Del(e) {
  db.allDocs({
    include_docs: true,
    descending: false
  }, function(err,
    doc) {
    db.remove(doc.rows[0].doc).then(function() {
      console.log("Success")
    }).catch(function() {
      console.log("Error")
    });
  })
};
```

Comment: You're specifying the first element (`doc.rows[0]`) - why then do you expect it to remove something else?

Comment: Actually i used loop here but that removed all the documents